# Is there a way to pass a Tab press to bash for completion in this case?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

There is a way to run commands in bash like this:

```
echo ls | bash
```

I need to unit-test bash completion, and I'm curisous if there is a way to pass a press to Tab this way to get the command completed, something like this:

```
# This doesn't work, but I think you get the idea
echo chromi$'\t' | bash
```

Is that possible? Or maybe you can suggest another way to unit-test bash completion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`compgen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins), a builtin command which lets you generates completion matches the same way bash does.

```
$ compgen -c unam
uname
```

Alternatively, run bash in interactive mode with `-i`. Then it will perform <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion.

```
$ bash -i <<< $'unam\t'
$ bash -i <<< $'unam\t'
$ uname 
Darwin
$ exit
```

Comment: Thanks, `$ bash -i <<< $'unam\t'` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ printf 'makeinf\t' | bash --norc -i
[user@host ~]$ makeinfo
[user@host ~]$ exit
```

works here. Set `PS1` as well if you don't need the prompt:

```
$ printf 'makeinf\t' | PS1='' bash --norc -i
makeinfo
exit
```